# Ubuntu stuck on loading on splash screen

Tags: boot, networking, software-installation, permissions, plymouth

I am on the latest Ubuntu and I’ve looked at similar questions and tried everything they’re saying and nothing is working for me and my cpu is kinda old tho

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: If you can't boot, then try booting with nomodeset, and do this edit. Or, do this edit in Recovery Mode.

You may have a problem with an older computer, with an older GPU. Try this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file if you're in Ubuntu

or

`sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file if you're in Recovery Mode

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`. Then reboot.